# How to get results from a query which is inside of a function

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to make an "AdminCheck" system which will check if the user is admin and return user's admin level based on information gathered from database

I've did some research and realized my problem is with query being asynchronous, but I couldn't find more

```js
function isAdmin(varr){
    let queryCheck = "SELECT AdminLVL FROM accounts WHERE username = ?"
    pool.query(queryCheck, [varr], (err,results) => {
        console.log(results[0].AdminLVL) // This gives me results
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else {
            return results[0].AdminLVL
        }
    })
}
```

right where I commented "This gives me results" everything works fine, but I wanna be able to use the result, which let's think its "300", somewhere else.

Comment: so, if you call `var admin = isAdmin('something')` from wherever in your code, what does return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the function calling isAdmin is running asynchronously, and not waiting for results. Change isAdmin to return a promise
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
Then you can write the rest of your code in isAdmin(varr).then(res => { // your code })
Or you can use async await.

edit to add some code:
Do something along these lines (view the docs to get it to work exactly as you need it to)

```
  isAdmin(varr) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let queryCheck = "SELECT AdminLVL FROM accounts WHERE username = ?"
        pool.query(queryCheck, [varr], (err,results) => {
            console.log(results[0].AdminLVL) // This gives me results
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(results[0].AdminLVL);
            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: now when I try to `console.log(isAdmin(varr))` I get `Promise { <pending> }` and my console.log within my query doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: do isAdmin(varr).then(res => {console.log(res)} if res contains the information you want, then you're good to go. Write all of your code that depends on the result inside of the then callback function.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning more about how asynchronous javascript works, then learn a bit more about promises and how they work. It might take a bit to wrap your head around, but once you've got it it will open up a whole new world for you, and might even just blow your mind. Then learn about async/ await. These concepts are crucial in both front and back end JS development.